# Numpy dType complexo, com array fixo de variaveis, usando função fromfile para importar arquivo binario

Tags: python, numpy

Eu estou lendo um arquivo binario complexo, onde existe uma estrutura fixa de 'array' de valores, alguem poderia ajudar?

A estrutura é:

```
   8 bytes     = Long    Current Time (unixtime stamp)
   8 bytes     = Long    Current Time (unixtime stamp in MiliSeconds)
   8 bytes     = Long    Server Time (unixtime stamp)
   8 bytes     = Long    Ticks from windows startup
   8 bytes     = Long    Microseconds from windows startup
   X[
      1 byte   = UChar (sensor on/off)
      8 bytes  = Double (sensor converted value)
      8 bytes  = Long (sensor raw value)
      ]
```

X é o array com 3 valores, o tamanho de X é fixo normalmente 32 ou 16, mas dentro do arquivo é sempre do mesmo tamanho, o exemplo que vou usar é 32:

```
   dt = np.dtype([('a'         ,np.datetime64),
           ('b'      ,np.datetime64),
           ('c'           ,np.datetime64),
           ('d'        ,'u8'),
           ('e' ,'u8'),

           #aqui esta o meu problema, como faço este trecho se repetir 32 vezes?
           {'name':   ['f', 'g', 'h'] , 'formats':['u1','f8', 'u8']}
   ])

   print(dt,type(dt))
   print(dt.fields)
   print(np.fromfile("sensores.32.bin", dtype=dt))
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: como altero o texto que ja escrevi? foi a primeira mensagem que postei aqui

Comment: Clica no botão [edit]

Comment: feito, obrigado @DenisRudneideSouza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, se eu entendi a questão acho que há uma solução assim

```
def make_dict(uri):

    my_fields = [
        'X{}-campo1'.format(uri), 
        'X{}-campo2'.format(uri),
        'X{}-campo3'.format(uri)
    ]

    my_formats = ['u1','f8', 'u8']

    return dict(name=my_fields, formats=my_formats)

my_arg  = [('campo1', np.datetime64),
           ('campo2', np.datetime64),
           ('campo3', np.datetime64),
           ('campo4', 'u8'),
           ('campo5', 'u8')]

for i in range(32):
    my_arg.append(make_dict(i+1))

dt = np.dtype(my_arg)

print(dt,type(dt))
print(dt.fields)
print(np.fromfile("sensores.32.bin", dtype=dt))
```

Comment: valeu, is acabei de fazer assim:


        names  =["a","b","c","d","e"]


        formats=["<u8", "<u8", "<u8", "<u8", "<u8"]


        for i in range(0,X):


            names.append("a"+str(i))


            names.append("b"+str(i))


            names.append("c"+str(i))


            formats.append("<u1")


            formats.append("<f8")


            formats.append("<u8")


        np.dtype({'names':names,'formats':formats})


agora falta fazer isso no pandas, mas seria outra pergunta ne' =)